# Requesting rep recalc

Tags: support, status-completed, rep-recalc

Can any of the mods please do a rep recalc on my account ? There's a rep difference of about 500 points between the rep on my current profile and the `/reputation` report, and I'd rather get it down now than have it climb to about 1000 points or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done. Recalculated.